# Загрузка графика и картинок во время скроллинга

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, изображения

Как сделать постепенную загрузку картинок и графика во время скроллинга как на этом сайте на этой странице http://www.adhamdannaway.com/about?

Как можно таким образом оживить интерфейс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Картинки загружаются с помощью [lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload). Проверка элементов на видимость с помощью [onScreen](http://benpickles.github.com/onScreen/). В принципе, этих двух плагинов должно хватить.

Comment: 1. Никаких картинок там нет.
2. Смысла подключать два плагина - тоже нет.

При скролле проверяем, когда блок будет на нужной нам позиции, а не в зоне видимости и, с помощью animate(), поочередно изменяем высоту каждого из элементов графика (в примере это <li>)