# Загрузка видимых картинок (Ленивая загрузка картинок)

Tags: javascript, html, изображения, оптимизация-сайтов, lazyloading

Как можно сделать так чтобы картинки грузились постепенно?

Нужно учитывать:

- размеры экраном бывают разные
- размеры картинок и их расположение разные
- картинка может быть например в слайдере, она есть на текущем экране, но именно в этот момент она не видна и не нужна
- вместо картинки нужно показывать заглушку, а если картинки разного размера...
- Решение должно быть без [jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/207012/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0) (возможно использование пакетов для [Angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular))
- Должны грузиться только картинки которые есть на текущем экране + 15%-30% со следующего экрана.
- При скролле должны подгружаться следующие картинки

PS. Это способ оптимизаций скорости загрузки сайта, и нагрузке серверов.

Comment: может быть есть другие варианты кроме моего?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл вот такой вариант:

```js
function isVisible(elem) {

  var coords = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

  // верхняя граница elem в пределах видимости ИЛИ нижняя граница видима
  var topVisible = coords.top > 0 && coords.top < windowHeight;
  var bottomVisible = coords.bottom < windowHeight && coords.bottom > 0;

  return topVisible || bottomVisible;
}
```

функция `isVisible` проверяет если картинка попадает в видимую часть экрана

```js
function showVisible() {
  var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {

    var img = imgs[i];

    var realsrc = img.getAttribute('realsrc');
    if (!realsrc) continue;

    if (isVisible(img)) {
      img.src = realsrc;
      img.setAttribute('realsrc', '');
    }
  }
}
```

а функция `showVisible` всем видимым картинкам меняет атрибут `src`, то есть показывает их

```js
window.onscroll = showVisible;
showVisible();
```

Comment: мой ответ соответствует не всем требованиям