# Lazyload для тега picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, изображения, lazyloading

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно лениво загружать (желательно по скроллу) картинки, которые собираются через тег `<picture>`?

Предположим для такой конструкции:

```html
<picture class="bl_games__image">
  <source media="(min-width: 2400px)" srcset="big_image.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source media="(min-width: 2400px)" srcset="big_image.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:320px)" srcset="middle_image.jpg">

  <img src="middle_image.jpg" alt="#">
</picture>
```

Я пробовал воспользоваться плагином [jQuery & Zepto](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/), но не пойму: как правильно добавлять `data-*` атрибуты и на что цеплять класс `.lazy`, чтобы это работало адекватно и для медиа-запросов.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/823513/256824